# memoir: is there a way to get a section of a certain level numbered sequentially throughout the book?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

I have to reset a book (original on paper only) of peculiar structure: it consists of more or less conventional parts and chapters, but sections (the lowest level division, and the only one explicitly numbered) are numbered in unbroken sequence throughout the book.

It looks like I'll have to do all the numbering (and the ToC) manually, as the idea runs counter to the LaTeX philosophy, unless I am unaware of some finer points.

Is there any hope of doing it the LaTeX/memoir way?

The required structure looks like this (I can't exactly wrap my head around it):

```
Foreword
Preface

Block 1
    Introduction
            Unit 1
            Unit 2
            Unit 3
    Theme 1
            Unit 4
            ...
            Unit 10
    Theme 2
            Unit 11
            ...
            Unit 18
    Theme 3
            Unit 19
            ...
            Unit 36
    Theme 4
        I Alfa
            Unit 37
            ...
            Unit 44
        II Bravo
            Unit 45
            ..
            Unit 49
        III Charlie
            Unit 50
            ...
            Unit 55
Block 2
    Theme 1
        I Delta
            Unit 1
            Unit 2
        II Echo
            Unit 3
            ...
            Unit 9
        III Foxtrot
            Unit 10
            ...
            Unit 15
        IV Golf
            Unit 15
            ...
            Unit 19
    Theme 2
            Unit 20
            ...
            Unit 37
    Theme 3
            Unit 38
            ...
            Unit 42
    Theme 4
            Unit 43
            ...
            Unit 54
Glossary
```

Everything should be in the ToC, of course. Is it still possible?

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}`. This will remove the resetting of the `section` counter by every new chapter.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `memoir` class simply put `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}` in your preamble; there is no need to use the `chngcntr` package as suggested by Christian Hupfer. For other classes go with Christian Hupfer's suggestion.

Comment: I didn't know that `memoir` has  a `\counterwithout` command

Comment: @Christian Hupfer That's alright. I have to keep looking in the manual to see what's there.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer check who's the original author of the package and memoir. Most of Peters stuff is directly embedded into memoir.

Comment: @daleif: I know who the original author is/was  ;-). I just had no idea that `memoir` has this feature

Comment: @ChristianHupfer even I still finds new features in memoir from time to time

Comment: @daleif: 'features' or features? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer features as in useful macros that might have gotten lost in the manual

Comment: Thanks! Actually it's a bit worse than that. The required structure looks like this:

Comment: And the memman documentation rather obscures, at least for me, how to use `\counterwithout` for such a purpose. (The only example I found there was how to use it to put tables and figures in the same squence.)

Answer (score 0):

This makes the division scheme look like I want it to:

```
%% Ensure sequential numbering of subsubsections.
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Must not precede the above
```

To put the starred versions of chapters/sections into the ToC:

```
    \section*{A Brief Course}
    \label{sec:brief}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:brief}}
```